# If my opponent casts Ultimate Price on my Phantasmal Bear, can I save it by casting Snap or Curfew?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I attack with [Phantasmal Bear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPhantasmal%20Bear%5d). My opponent responds by casting [Ultimate Price](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUltimate%20Price%5d) and targets my bear. Can I save my creature by casting [Snap](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnap%5d) or [Curfew](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurfew%5d)? If I had a regular creature, I know that Curfew would be able to save because I would just return it to my hand and my opponents Ultimate Price would have an illegal target and fizzle out. But, I'm supposed to sacrifice Phantasmal Bear when it becomes targeted. So I'm just very confused on whether my bear will lose the target when I cast Curfew or automatically die because it was previously targeted. (I know now most illusions don't have that ability, but my whole deck has creatures with that ability so its very important)

Comment: Can you clean up your question to focus on what you are asking and less back story please. It is hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Just so you know, most illusion creatures do not in fact have that ability, so you should probably quote the exact ability you are talking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can save your Phantasmal Bear with Curfew, but not with Snap.

The "illusion ability" is a triggered ability, and once it triggers it goes on the stack on top of whatever spell or ability triggered it. So, after your opponent casts the Ultimate Price, the triggered ability goes on the stack and then you have the opportunity to respond. If you respond by casting Curfew, you can choose to put the Phantasmal Bear into your hand, which will save it from both its own ability and the removal spell. If you instead respond with Snap, Snap itself targets the creature, so the illusion ability will trigger again and go onto the stack on top of Snap, and you will have to sacrifice the creature before Snap resolves.

Comment: Thank you so much. Still confused about the Snap part though because why would it matter if the creature got targeted twice?

Comment: Which part of my explanation of why that happens is not clear to you?

Comment: Every time the bear is targeted its ability will trigger, even if a copy of that ability is already on the stack.

Comment: @user27103 The important distinction between Snap and Curfew is that Snap targets, and would hence put another trigger on the stack (Phantasmal bear's triggered ability), whereas Curfew does not target (and hence does not put another trigger on the stack, and therefore Curfew resolves before the triggers resolve).